# How to remove element in a certain set which is stored in Arraylist of Set in JAVA?

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I have a problem on removing an element in a certain set which is stored in Arraylist of Set in JAVA.

My code is like this :

```
public class Classroom {

    private ArrayList<Set<Integer>> arrSetSlot;
    private Set<Integer> SetSlot;

    public Classrom(){
        arrSetSlot = new ArrayList();
    }

    public ArrayList<Set<Integer>> getHimpWaktu_tersedia() {
        return arrSetSlot;
    }

    public void addSlotWaktu(int kromosom, int Slot){
        arrSetSlot.get(kromosom).add(Slot);
    }    

    public void addSlotWaktu(Set<Integer> SetSlot){
        arrSetSlot.add(SetSlot);
    }
}


public class Inisialisasi {
    ArrayList<Classrom> arrClassroom;
    Set<Integer> SetSlot;
    Database d;

    public Inisialisasi(){
        arrClassroom=new ArrayList();
        SetSlot=new HashSet();
        d = new Database();
        loadDatabase();
        validasiData();
    }

    private void loadDatabase(){
        for (int i=1;i<41;i++){
            SetSlot.add(i);
        }

        rs=d.getData("select* from kelas");
        try {
            while(rs.next()){
                Classroom kelas = new Classroom();
                kelas.setIdKelas(rs.getString("id_kelas"));
                kelas.setKodeKelas(rs.getString("kode_kelas"));
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                    kelas.addSlotWaktu(SetSlot);
                }
                arrKelas.add(kelas);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Inisialisasi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private void validasiData(){
        //the problematic remove
        arrKelas.get(2).getHimpWaktu_tersedia().get(2).remove(1);
        for (int i=0;i<arrKelas.get(1).getHimpWaktu_tersedia().size();i++){
            System.out.println(arrKelas.get(1).getHimpWaktu_tersedia().get(i).size());
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to remove elements from certain set in the array using this function :
classroom.getArrSetSlot.get(1).remove(1);

It was not only removing the element "1" from the first set but also removing element "1" from all sets in the arraylist..

Any solution for this problem??
Thanks

Comment: Please post the code where you put multiple references to the same set into your list, instead of creating new sets.

Comment: Ceck your code again, test to see if it really does what you write here it does. (Would only happen if all of the elements of the ArrayList was the exact same set)

Comment: Post the code that calls `arrSetSlot.add`.

Comment: Classroom has no method `getArrSetSlot` as far as we can see.

Comment: Probable explanation is that you are using the same set reference in all your array list elements added.

Comment: all of the elements of the ArrayList was indeed the exact same set. then how to solve this problem??

Comment: @darkaziz Evidently the oposite, use a different set per every array list entry added so that every one can be manipulated individually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

```
public void addSlotWaktu(Set<Integer> SetSlot){
    arrSetSlot.add(SetSlot);
}
```

should probably be

```
public void addSlotWaktu(Set<Integer> SetSlot){
    arrSetSlot.add(new HashSet<Integer>(SetSlot));
}
```

assuming that you want a new independent copy of that set in the slot.

Comment: ah.. sorry for little mistake.. I tried to convert the name from Indonesian to English.. so it's actually like that. the process of adding the set into the arraylist happened here :  `for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                    kelas.addSlotWaktu(SetSlot);
                }`

Comment: @darkaziz (re: comment update) or you can make the `new` set there.

Comment: If it answered your question, you should accept the answer by clicking the gray check box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arrSetSlot = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
```